# Vuetify V2: v-col as section for divider with gradient that extends outside of its bounds?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, clip-path

So the wavy gradient + clip-path sections have been in vogue for a bit e.g. [image] or [image]

I was curious of how to emulate this in a nuxt + vuetify (v2) application. 
From the Vuetify v2, the [grid documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids):

- `v-container`: provides the ability to center and horizontally pad your site's contents
- `v-row`: (replaces `v-layout`) control the layout and flow of its inner columns
- `v-col`: (replaces `v-flex`) is a content holder that must be a direct child of `v-row`

and the with a default nuxt app setup with vuetify:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-container>
      <nuxt />
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

and I am using `<v-row>` as sections in the following manner (e.g. `index.vue`)

```html
<v-row> <!-- <nuxt/> -->
  <v-col cols="12> <!-- section 1 -->
    ...
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12> <!-- section 1 -->
    ..
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

My question is how I can have thes `v-col`s ("sections") that are nested inside `v-container/nuxt/v-row` have a gradient and clip-path curve that extends the *width* of the app rather than the width of the column with the padding, margins, etc